# Insert new node in a binary search tree at C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, nodes

I already have a binary search tree with 5 levels, I am trying to create a function which inserts a new node but I can't do it working right. How can I edit my code to do the insertion?

```
TREE *insertion(TREE *root, int num){
    TREE *node, *new_node;
    node = root;
    new_node=(TREE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    new_node->rec = num;
    new_node->lp = NULL;
    new_node->rp = NULL;

    while(node != NULL ){
//      if(node->rec == num){
//          printf("This value exists\n");
//          return NULL;            
//      }
        if(num > node->rec){
            node = node->rp;    
        }
        else
            node = node->lp;
    }

    if(num>node->rec)
        node = new_node;
    else
        node = new_node;

    return root;}
```

Comment: What do the function *return*? What is it *supposed* to return?

Comment: Nothing just insert the new node at the right place.

Comment: And yet you have declared that the function should return a `TREE*`? If you declare a function to return something, it *must* return something, otherwise you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: On another note, where will `node` point after the loop?

Comment: The first return that is NULL is not important. I edited my code to return the tree's root but nothing works though. The thing is that the node is not being inserted.

Comment: That is my problem the fact that i don't undestand where the pointer is after the while.

Comment: Hint: The loop ends when `node == NULL`.

Comment: Lastly, Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). A couple of minutes in a debugger would have given you all the information you needed and more.

Comment: Yes and there is where I am trying to insert the new node. I edited my code again. Can you please check it out again?

Comment: `node = new_node;` which? `node->left` or `node->right`?

Comment: Before I edited my code it was like this `node->rp = new_node;` and `node->lp = new_node;` but it wasn't working.

Comment: `I already have a binary search tree with 5 levels` - how did that tree come about? Make your code work for one node, then two, then three, and so on - and try different  key orders as well for each number of nodes. Most people would code this as a recursive function, which returns the (possibly new) root of the sub-tree and assigns this value to the current left or right child (except for at the root level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this `num > node->rec` is true you need to check whether `node->rp` is `NULL` or not, which you didn't check.

Also pass the *address* of `head` to `insertion()` so that modification in passed variable `head` affects in calling function and you no need to return anything.

Assume you are calling `insertion()` like below

```
int main(void) {
        TREE *head = NULL;
        insertion(&head,10);/* pass the  address of head so that modification will affect here also otherwise just passing head means it will treat as call by value */
        insertion(&head,5);
        insertion(&head,15);
        return 0;
}
```

And `insertion()` function looks like

```
int  insertion(TREE **root, int num) {
        TREE *node, *new_node;
        node = *root;
        new_node = malloc(sizeof(TREE)); /* no need of casting malloc() results */
        new_node->rec = num;
        new_node->lp = NULL;
        new_node->rp = NULL;

        while(node != NULL ){
                if(node->rec == num){
                        printf("This value exists\n");
                        return NULL;`
                }

                if(num > node->rec){ /* right child of root node */
                        if(node->rp != NULL) { /* check node->rp is empty or not
                                                  if not, update node.. check here itself */
                                node = node->rp; /* update node */
                        }
                        else {
                                node->rp = new_node; /* insert new node */
                                return; /* new node added at correct position , so no need of any further processing, jut return */
                        }
                }
                else {
                        if(node->lp != NULL) {
                                node = node->lp;
                        }
                        else {
                                node->lp = new_node;
                                return;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. :)